# How can the channel capacity be larger than one, in the noisy channel coding theorem?

Tags: information-theory

The Noisy channel coding theorem stated that:
For every discrete memoryless channel, the channel capacity
$C=\sup\{{I(X,Y)}\}$ has the following property:
For any $\epsilon>0$ and $R<C$, for large enough N, there exists a code of length N and rate ≥ R and a decoding algorithm, such that the maximal probability of block error is less than $\epsilon$. 
We know that chances are that the capacity C is larger than one. For example, if C=3 and we choose R=1.5, how can the rate of a code be 1.5?

Comment: It seems you think that the rate of a code cannot be greater than one. This is indeed the case if the alphabet of the codeword elements is binary. However, one can use a code based on an alphabet with more than two elements and the rate can indeed become greater than one. Review the definition of the rate and you should be convinced about that. Your question seems to have nothing to do with the notions of capacity and the channel coding theorem.

Comment: @Stelios Perhaps that comment should be an answer?